# List of Spring Runtime Exceptions

Tags: spring, exception, spring-mvc, spring-3, runtimeexception

Does anyone know where I can find a list of Spring's (3.0.x) runtime exceptions? I'm talking about exceptions like `DataRetrievalFailureException`; there's a whole set of these runtime exceptions that you can throw.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Alright, I was able to find them by loading up the source for Spring in my IDE, and seeing all the classes that extend the `NestedRuntimeException` abstract class. Keep in mind that some of these are abstract classes themselves, and so you will have to use the appropriate concrete implementation:

- [`AopConfigException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/AopConfigException.html)
- [`AopInvocationException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/AopInvocationException.html)
- [`ApplicationContextException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextException.html)
- [`BadSqlGrammarException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/BadSqlGrammarException.html)
- [`BeanCreationException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanCreationException.html)
- [`BeanCreationNotAllowedException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanCreationNotAllowedException.html)
- [`BeanCurrentlyInCreationException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanCurrentlyInCreationException.html)
- [`BeanDefinitionParsingException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/parsing/BeanDefinitionParsingException.html)
- [`BeanDefinitionStoreException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanDefinitionStoreException.html)
- [`BeanDefinitionValidationException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionValidationException.html)
- [`BeanExpressionException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanExpressionException.html)
- [`BeanInitializationException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanInitializationException.html)
- [`BeanInstantiationException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanInstantiationException.html)
- [`BeanIsAbstractException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanIsAbstractException.html)
- [`BeanIsNotAFactoryException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanIsNotAFactoryException.html)
- [`BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException.html)
- [`BeansException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeansException.html)
- [`BootstrapException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/access/BootstrapException.html)
- [`BshScriptUtils.BshExecutionException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scripting/bsh/BshScriptUtils.BshExecutionException.html)
- [`CannotAcquireLockException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/CannotAcquireLockException.html)
- [`CannotCreateRecordException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jca/cci/CannotCreateRecordException.html)
- [`CannotCreateTransactionException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/CannotCreateTransactionException.html)
- [`CannotGetCciConnectionException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jca/cci/CannotGetCciConnectionException.html)
- [`CannotGetJdbcConnectionException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/CannotGetJdbcConnectionException.html)
- [`CannotLoadBeanClassException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/CannotLoadBeanClassException.html)
- [`CannotSerializeTransactionException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/CannotSerializeTransactionException.html)
- [`CciOperationNotSupportedException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jca/cci/CciOperationNotSupportedException.html)
- [`CleanupFailureDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/CleanupFailureDataAccessException.html)
- [`ConcurrencyFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/ConcurrencyFailureException.html)
- [`ConversionException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/ConversionException.html)
- [`ConversionFailedException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/ConversionFailedException.html)
- [`ConversionNotSupportedException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/ConversionNotSupportedException.html)
- [`ConverterNotFoundException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/ConverterNotFoundException.html)
- [`DataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html)
- [`DataAccessResourceFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessResourceFailureException.html)
- [`DataIntegrityViolationException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataIntegrityViolationException.html)
- [`DataRetrievalFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataRetrievalFailureException.html)
- [`DataSourceLookupFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/DataSourceLookupFailureException.html)
- [`DeadlockLoserDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DeadlockLoserDataAccessException.html)
- [`DuplicateKeyException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DuplicateKeyException.html)
- [`EjbAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ejb/access/EjbAccessException.html)
- [`EmptyResultDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/EmptyResultDataAccessException.html)
- [`FactoryBeanNotInitializedException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBeanNotInitializedException.html)
- [`FatalBeanException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/FatalBeanException.html)
- [`HandlerMethodInvocationException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/support/HandlerMethodInvocationException.html)
- [`HeuristicCompletionException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/HeuristicCompletionException.html)
- [`HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException.html)
- [`HttpClientErrorException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpClientErrorException.html)
- [`HttpMessageConversionException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConversionException.html)
- [`HttpMessageNotReadableException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageNotReadableException.html)
- [`HttpMessageNotWritableException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageNotWritableException.html)
- [`HttpServerErrorException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpServerErrorException.html)
- [`HttpStatusCodeException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpStatusCodeException.html)
- [`IllegalTransactionStateException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/IllegalTransactionStateException.html)
- [`IncorrectResultSetColumnCountException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/IncorrectResultSetColumnCountException.html)
- [`IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException.html)
- [`IncorrectUpdateSemanticsDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/IncorrectUpdateSemanticsDataAccessException.html)
- [`InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException.html)
- [`InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException.html)
- [`InvalidIsolationLevelException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/InvalidIsolationLevelException.html)
- [`InvalidMetadataException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jmx/export/metadata/InvalidMetadataException.html)
- [`InvalidPropertyException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/InvalidPropertyException.html)
- [`InvalidResultSetAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jca/cci/InvalidResultSetAccessException.html)
- [`InvalidResultSetAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/InvalidResultSetAccessException.html)
- [`InvalidTimeoutException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/InvalidTimeoutException.html)
- [`InvocationFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jmx/access/InvocationFailureException.html)
- [`JaxRpcSoapFaultException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/jaxrpc/JaxRpcSoapFaultException.html)
- [`JaxWsSoapFaultException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/jaxws/JaxWsSoapFaultException.html)
- [`JdbcUpdateAffectedIncorrectNumberOfRowsException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/JdbcUpdateAffectedIncorrectNumberOfRowsException.html)
- [`JdoOptimisticLockingFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jdo/JdoOptimisticLockingFailureException.html)
- [`JmxException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jmx/JmxException.html)
- [`JndiLookupFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiLookupFailureException.html)
- [`JobMethodInvocationFailedException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/JobMethodInvocationFailedException.html)
- [`JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException.html)
- [`JRubyScriptUtils.JRubyExecutionException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scripting/jruby/JRubyScriptUtils.JRubyExecutionException.html)
- [`LobRetrievalFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/LobRetrievalFailureException.html)
- [`MailAuthenticationException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/MailAuthenticationException.html)
- [`MailException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/MailException.html)
- [`MailParseException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/MailParseException.html)
- [`MailPreparationException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/MailPreparationException.html)
- [`MailSendException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/MailSendException.html)
- [`MaxUploadSizeExceededException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MaxUploadSizeExceededException.html)
- [`MBeanConnectFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jmx/access/MBeanConnectFailureException.html)
- [`MBeanExportException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jmx/export/MBeanExportException.html)
- [`MBeanInfoRetrievalException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jmx/access/MBeanInfoRetrievalException.html)
- [`MBeanServerNotFoundException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jmx/MBeanServerNotFoundException.html)
- [`MessageConversionException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/converter/MessageConversionException.html)
- [`MetaDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/MetaDataAccessException.html)
- [`MethodInvocationException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/MethodInvocationException.html)
- [`MultipartException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartException.html)
- [`NestedTransactionNotSupportedException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/NestedTransactionNotSupportedException.html)
- [`NonTransientDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/NonTransientDataAccessException.html)
- [`NonTransientDataAccessResourceException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/NonTransientDataAccessResourceException.html)
- [`NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.html)
- [`NotAnAtAspectException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/aspectj/annotation/NotAnAtAspectException.html)
- [`NoTransactionException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/NoTransactionException.html)
- [`NotReadablePropertyException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/NotReadablePropertyException.html)
- [`NotWritablePropertyException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/NotWritablePropertyException.html)
- [`NullValueInNestedPathException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/NullValueInNestedPathException.html)
- [`ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException.html)
- [`OptimisticLockingFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/OptimisticLockingFailureException.html)
- [`PermissionDeniedDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/PermissionDeniedDataAccessException.html)
- [`PessimisticLockingFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/PessimisticLockingFailureException.html)
- [`PropertyAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/PropertyAccessException.html)
- [`RecordTypeNotSupportedException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jca/cci/RecordTypeNotSupportedException.html)
- [`RecoverableDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/RecoverableDataAccessException.html)
- [`RemoteAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/RemoteAccessException.html)
- [`RemoteConnectFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/RemoteConnectFailureException.html)
- [`RemoteInvocationFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/RemoteInvocationFailureException.html)
- [`RemoteLookupFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/RemoteLookupFailureException.html)
- [`RemoteProxyFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/RemoteProxyFailureException.html)
- [`ResourceAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/ResourceAccessException.html)
- [`RestClientException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestClientException.html)
- [`SchedulingException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/SchedulingException.html)
- [`ScriptCompilationException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scripting/ScriptCompilationException.html)
- [`SerializationFailedException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/serializer/support/SerializationFailedException.html)
- [`SoapFaultException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/soap/SoapFaultException.html)
- [`SQLWarningException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/SQLWarningException.html)
- [`SqlXmlFeatureNotImplementedException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/xml/SqlXmlFeatureNotImplementedException.html)
- [`TransactionException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionException.html)
- [`TransactionSuspensionNotSupportedException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionSuspensionNotSupportedException.html)
- [`TransactionSystemException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionSystemException.html)
- [`TransactionTimedOutException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionTimedOutException.html)
- [`TransactionUsageException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionUsageException.html)
- [`TransientDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/TransientDataAccessException.html)
- [`TransientDataAccessResourceException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/TransientDataAccessResourceException.html)
- [`TypeMismatchDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/TypeMismatchDataAccessException.html)
- [`TypeMismatchException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/TypeMismatchException.html)
- [`UnableToRegisterMBeanException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jmx/export/UnableToRegisterMBeanException.html)
- [`UnableToSendNotificationException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jmx/export/notification/UnableToSendNotificationException.html)
- [`UncategorizedDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/UncategorizedDataAccessException.html)
- [`UncategorizedSQLException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/UncategorizedSQLException.html)
- [`UnexpectedRollbackException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/UnexpectedRollbackException.html)
- [`UnsatisfiedDependencyException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/UnsatisfiedDependencyException.html)
- [`XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException.html)

Comment: It will be even more usefull if you sort them in alphabetical order. (BTW after that you can see that there about 20 duplicated class names.)